# Loading custom prj conflicts with existing CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, prj

I'm using ESRI Basemap (EPSG:3857) in QGIS. I downloaded some government data but the `.prj`-file (Clarke_1866_Transverse_Mercator) is not being used. Instead, QGIS loads in EPSG:2016 and it's not showing the layer.

When I try to create a custom CRS using the data from the `.prj`-file, QGIS prevents me from stating it is the same as EPSG:2016.

Here is the data `.prj`-file:

```
PROJCS["Clarke_1866_Transverse_Mercator",
GEOGCS["GCS_Clarke_1866",DATUM["D_unknown",
SPHEROID["clrk66",6378206.4,294.9786982]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["false_easting",304800.0],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0.0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",-79.5],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9999],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0.0],
UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Comment: Have you tried to zoom to the extent of the invisible layer? Or try to load only that layer into an empty project. Have you checked if there were any features in that layer? Open attribute table, is it empty?

Comment: I have tried loading into a new empty project. It is not empty. I can see data when the project is assigned EPSG:2016 intsead of basemap CRS. But t becomes wrongly located on the basemap. I tried to create a custom CRS using the .prj-file just slightly different from so it wont conflict with EPSG:2016 and the data is aligned correctly to basemap works (just slightly off). Now I'm thinking if I can just delete the existing EPSG:2016 file. Where can I locate this definition and delete it?

Comment: Are you sure the EPSG code is correct? Check the coordinates in the empty project. Are they correct? If your definition is the same as the stored in QGIS, no sense to delete from the srs.db (sqlite database where QGIS stores projection definitions).

Comment: Yes, it's correct because my custom one conflicts with it. BUT something is not exactly the same with the default one that's making it not work with this data. Like I mention, if i adjust the custom one to be slightly different then it's I can see the data appear in the almost right location.

Comment: I am stumped. EPSG:2016 no longer appears in QGIS but I still can't create a custom CRS because it's still being recognized as the same?

"Cannot save 'Clarke_1866_Transverse_Mercator' — the definition is equivalent to EPSG:2016.

(Try removing "ID["EPSG",2016]" from the WKT definition."